# pygame keyup not registering correctly

Tags: python, pygame, keypress, keyup

I made a game that just detects movements of 2 players, but sometimes, when multiple keys are pressed at once and then let off, it doesn't detect that all of the keys had been let off (one of the keys is still counted as pressed).I tried calling the "keyup" function multiple times in program, but it doesn't seem to help.It also happens with just one player, but more rarely since less keys are pressed at one moment.
Here's the code:

`import pygame,sys

pygame.init()

DPROZOR=(1200,800)
DIGRAC=(100,100)
KORAK=0.5

ziv=True
x1,y1=(float(DPROZOR[0]/2-DIGRAC[0]/2),float(DPROZOR[1]-DIGRAC[1]))
x2,y2=(float(DPROZOR[0]/2-DIGRAC[0]/2),0)
pozicija1=[x1,y1]
pozicija2=[x2,y2]
desno1,levo1,gore1,dole1=(False,False,False,False)
desno2,levo2,gore2,dole2=(False,False,False,False)

prozor=pygame.display.set_mode(DPROZOR)

def crtaj():
    prozor.fill(pygame.Color("skyblue"))
    pygame.draw.rect(prozor,pygame.Color("gold"),(pozicija1,DIGRAC))
    pygame.draw.rect(prozor, pygame.Color("red"), (pozicija2, DIGRAC))

def keyDown1():
    global desno1,levo1,gore1,dole1

    if(event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
        if(event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT): desno1=True
        if(event.key == pygame.K_LEFT): levo1=True
        if(event.key == pygame.K_UP): gore1=True
        if(event.key == pygame.K_DOWN): dole1=True

def keyDown2():
    global desno2,levo2,gore2,dole2

    if(event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
        if(event.key == pygame.K_d): desno2=True
        if(event.key == pygame.K_a): levo2=True
        if(event.key == pygame.K_w): gore2=True
        if(event.key == pygame.K_s): dole2=True

def keyUp1():
    global desno1,levo1,gore1,dole1

    if(event.type == pygame.KEYUP):
        if(event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT): desno1=False
        if(event.key == pygame.K_LEFT): levo1=False
        if(event.key == pygame.K_UP): gore1=False
        if(event.key == pygame.K_DOWN): dole1=False

def keyUp2():
    global desno2,levo2,gore2,dole2

    if(event.type == pygame.KEYUP):
        if(event.key == pygame.K_d): desno2=False
        if(event.key == pygame.K_a): levo2=False
        if(event.key == pygame.K_w): gore2=False
        if(event.key == pygame.K_s): dole2=False

def kretanje1():
    global x1,y1,pozicija1

    if(desno1): x1+=KORAK
    if(levo1): x1-=KORAK
    if(x1 < 0): x1+=KORAK
    if(x1 > DPROZOR[0] - DIGRAC[0]): x1-=KORAK

    if(gore1): y1-=KORAK
    if(dole1): y1+=KORAK
    if(y1 < 0): y1+=KORAK
    if(y1 > DPROZOR[1] - DIGRAC[1]): y1-=KORAK

    pozicija1=[x1,y1]

def kretanje2():
    global x2,y2,pozicija2

    if(desno2): x2+=KORAK
    if(levo2): x2-=KORAK
    if(x2 < 0): x2+=KORAK
    if(x2 > DPROZOR[0] - DIGRAC[0]): x2-=KORAK

    if(gore2): y2-=KORAK
    if(dole2): y2+=KORAK
    if(y2 < 0): y2+=KORAK
    if(y2 > DPROZOR[1] - DIGRAC[1]): y2-=KORAK

    pozicija2=[x2,y2]

while ziv:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    crtaj()

    keyDown1()
    kretanje1()
    keyUp1()
    kretanje1()

    keyDown2()
    kretanje2()
    keyUp2()
    kretanje2()

    print()
    print(desno1,levo1,gore1,dole1)
    print()
    print(desno2,levo2,gore2,dole2)
    print()

    pygame.display.update()`

levo=left

desno=right

gore=up

dole=down

ziv=alive

DPROZOR=window dimensions

DIGRAC=player dimensions

KORAK=step

pozicija=pozition

kretanje=movement

crtaj=draw

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to evaluate the events in the event loop rather than the application loop:

```py
while ziv:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        keyDown1()
        kretanje1()
        keyUp1()
        kretanje1()

        keyDown2()
        kretanje2()
        keyUp2()
        kretanje2() 

    crtaj()

    # [...]
```

Comment: Before anything else... Thank you for answering... Although that fixed my keylag problem, it also made it so i can not have continuous movement. It does 1 step every time I press a key. I am looking forward to figuring out not only how to fix that, but also why it happened in the first place :)